# Finding orthogonal basis in $\mathbb R^4$ from given vectors

Tags: orthogonality

I have two subsets of $\mathbb R^4$

$S=((-1,0,1,1),(0,1,1,1),(1,0,0,1))$

and 
$T=(x,y,z,x-y+2z)$

I've proved that T is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ and that S is a basis for T.  So far, so good!

I have to show that 2 of the vectors are orthogonal, which I have done, namely $(-1,0,1,1)$ and $(1,0,0,1)$ as their product is equal to zero.  I now need to find an orthogonal basis for "T".

I presume I need to use Gram-Schmidt process, but am struggling as to how to find two more orthogonal vectors to start with.  Would any starting vector need to be in the form $(x,y,z,x-y+2z)$?

Any hints/help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why two more vectors? Since $\dim T=3$, you only need *one* more vector. So, apply Gram-Schmidt to $e_1=(-1,0,1,1)$, $e_2=(1,0,0,1)$, and $e_3=(0,1,1,1)$. The fact that $e_1$ and $e_2$ are orthogonal will make your computations easier.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had tried this, done my calculations slightly wrong and ended up with something not orthogonal as the answer, so had presumed it was the wrong way to do it!  Done again, and have an orthogonal basis!  Worth asking for clarification..thanks again!

Comment: Then you should have obtained$$\frac1{\sqrt3}\left(-1,0,0,1\right),\ \frac1{\sqrt2}(1,0,0,1)\text{, and }\frac1{\sqrt{42}}(1,6,2,-1).$$

Comment: actually i had a different answer but presuming that yours is the orthonormal basis?

Comment: This basis is the one that is obtained by applying Gram-Schmidt to the basis from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If "S is basis for T" and S has only 3 vektor in it, then you can assume, that dim(T) = 3 so you don't need two more vektors.
Just use the Gram-Schmidt process on those 3 basevektors in S.
But as we know that two of them are orthogonal, you just need to sove the last one.